# Having Docker access External files

Tags: docker, volume

I am interested in having Docker have access to external files, but I do not wish to include them as a volume.  The files that I need access to will change over time, and this means I would need to re-mount repeatedly, unless I can mount a mere directory, and whatever is in that directory is also mounted.

I am just in need of allowing a software program pushed into a container, to run "over" my local system, where this software program has access to files on my local system.

Advice?  Is there another way besides adding the files needing to be processed as a volume?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I solved the same problem with below commands

```
docker run  --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/data,target=/home/data -it <name_of_container>
```

> Note "-it conainter_name" should be the last flags.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like mounting a host directory in the container is what you're looking for. You won't have to restart the container to pick up changes to the mounted directory. [Link to relevant docs.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the [ADD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) command could help you accomplish your goal. For instance, given the Dockerfile line:

```
ADD /Users/userX/myappfiles /appfiles
```

and the command line:

```
docker run myapp --input /myappfiles
```

`myapp` would be able to access `/Users/userX/myappfiles` on the local filesystem to fetch its inputs.

Comment: Does ADD command copies the file or folder. Depending on Op's needs, that may not be what they want. If they want to share the data, and see any updates made to it, than that won't work, because any changes made within the Docker container won't be accessible outside the container. And since it copies files, if those files are large, it could consume a lot of CPU and disk space copying them every time the container is spun up.

Comment: Yes, `ADD` copies files/folder and your concerns are valid.